# Block HTTP_X_FORWADED_FOR by iptables

Tags: nginx, iptables

I have to 2 servers:
 - front
 - backend

Front server is a proxy to backend
I have no access to front server.

So..

How i can block ip address in backend, if i see real ip only in `http_x_forwaded_for` header?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not.

You can:

- **block the IP on front server** - this is the way you must do it.
  also is probably good idea to firewall backend server from all IP addresses but front server and probably your administrative IP's.
- use webserver on backend to block based on the header.
  on `Apache` this can be done with `.htaccess`.
- on backend, use the scripting language (`PHP` or whatever) to show blank page based on the header.